# Unable to debug "xpath is invalid"

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt

I'm new to xml and xsl
here's my xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>

            <head><title>TV Shows</title></head>
            <body>

            <xsl:for-each select="tvshow/show">

                <a href="#{generate-id(name)}"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/></a><br />

            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="tvshow/show" >

                <xsl:sort select="name" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>

                <h3><a name="{generate-id(name)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/></a></h3>

                <img> 
                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                    <xsl:value-of select="poster/@href" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                </img>

                <p>The show <xsl:value-of select="name"/> was released in <xsl:value-of select="release"/>
                 by <xsl:value-of select="network"/>. It had an average viewership of <xsl:value-of select="viwers"/>.
                 It was cancelled in <xsl:value-of select="end_date"/>.</p>

            </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tvshow.xsl" ?>

<tvshow>

    <show>

        <name>Life On Mars</name>
        <release>2008</release>
        <end_date>2009</end_date>
        <network country="US">ABC</network>

        <poster
            href="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTM4MDg2NTk1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzI4OTY5MQ@@._V1._SY317_CR12,0,214,317_.jpg"
            width="214" height="317" />

        <viewers units="millions">7.82</viewers>


    </show>

    <show>
        <name>Life On Mars</name>
        <release>2006</release>
        <end_date>2007</end_date>
        <network country="UK">BBC</network>
        <poster
            href="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQxNzc5MjQwNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjU3Njc4Mg@@._V1._SY317_CR8,0,214,317_.jpg"
            width="214" height="317" />
        <viewers units="millions">6.8</viewers>
    </show>

    <show>
        <name>Freaks and Geeks</name>
        <release>1999</release>
        <end_date>2000</end_date>
        <network country="US">ABC</network>
        <poster
            href="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ5OTEzODYyMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjcxNTcwMg@@._V1._SY317_CR24,0,214,317_.jpg"
            width="214" height="317" />
        <viewers units="millions">6.77</viewers>
    </show>

</tvshow>
```

when I try to open the xml file in a browser, it says, "Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later."
Eclipse is throwing an error:"xpath is invalid" on xls file, line 39, ""
Please help me resolve this issue. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using the code you have posted. Which browser are you using?

Comment: eclipse's web browswe, chrome and internet explorer

Comment: doesn't seem to work in any

Comment: Chrome is not a good tool to test this (do a search). But there is no error in the stylesheet - see: http://xsltransform.net/bwdwrS